# Confused about the scope of variable in python

Tags: python, scope

I was studying merge sort and I wrote this code

```
def mergesort(a): #sorting algo
    #code is alright just confused about scope of variable
    if(len(a)>1):
        mid = len(a)//2
        l = a[:mid]
        r = a[mid:]
        mergesort(l)
        mergesort(r)
        i=j=k=0
        while(i<len(l) and j<len(r)):
            if(l[i]>r[j]):
                a[k] = r[j]
                j+=1
            else:
                a[k] = l[i]
                i+=1
            k+=1
        
        while(i<len(l)):
            a[k] = l[i]
            i+=1
            k+=1

        while(j<len(r)):
            a[k] = r[j]
            j+=1
            k+=1        

a = [30,2,4,5,-1,3,7,3,9,2,5]
mergesort(a)
print(a)
```

here `a` is a global variable, but when the function parameter name is also `a` doesn't the `a` in  function scope override the `a` in the global scope? how the global variable is getting edited inside `mergesort` function?

I tried another code with same approach but here the global variable doesn't get edited(as expected),how is this different from the above code?

```
def foo(a):
    a=20

a = 10
foo(a)
print(a)
```

Comment: `a[index] = value` and `a = value` are defferent behaviors.

Comment: Try renaming `a` in one of those scopes and you'll see that it behaves exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that `a` is global (because it's not). The `a` is local to the function, but it references the same list as the global `a` (because variables are passed by reference in python).

`a` is a list (which is mutable) in the first example, while `a` is an integer (which is immutable) in the second example. So changing values *inside* of the list (like `a[k] = l[i]`), changes the global list as well, while changing the reference to an integer (like `a = 20`) only replaces the local reference.

If you don't want the function to change the global list, you can fix it by creating a copy of the list:

```
def mergesort(a):
    a = a[:] # or a = a.copy(), whichever you prefer
    ...
```

Note that in this case, the function has no effect, so you'd probably want to return the resulting list.

Comment: That's not really a "fix". OP's function doesn't return anything, so copying the list means that it has no effect.

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, you're right, this function wouldn't have any effect as it is now. But if OP was concerned that it changes the global list, he might want this function to return something after all. I'll update the answer to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Totally, you'd just need to add `return a` at the end and capture the recursive results.

Answer (score 1):

Lists are mutable but int is not. So when you change int, you get an entirely new int. When you make changes **within** a list, you don't get a new list. You just have a modified list.

So when you pass the list to a function, it does not create a new list unless you do something like this: `a.copy()` or `a[:]` which creates a new list. In your case, you are using the same list as outside the function.

For more info read about **mutability of data types** or **pass by reference and pass by value**.